# insert linked list nodes in a loop

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm using strtok() to parse an input, convert the string into an int and then insert this int value into a linked list all in a while loop.

This is what I'm trying to do (I haven't written the code explicitly but I'm planning to do do something as follows):

```
while(fgets(&string,LMAX,fp) != NULL){

//get first token using strtok
//convert to int
//insert into linked list

while (token != NULL){

//get next token in the line
//do the same as above
}
}
```

I already have written a function that is supposed to insert a node into the linked list and it is as follows:

```
void insert_node(struct Cons *head_pointer, int data){
struct Cons *new = (struct Cons*) malloc(sizeof(struct Cons));
struct Cons *current = head_pointer;
new->head = data;
new->tail = NULL;

if (head_pointer->tail == NULL){
head_pointer->tail = new;
}
else
{

while (current->tail != NULL){
current = current->tail;
}
current->tail = new;
}
free(current);
current = NULL;
}
```

The struct definition is also as follows:

```
typedef int element_t;

typedef
struct Cons {
  element_t head;
  struct Cons* tail;
} Cons;
```

Can anyone suggest how I can go about doing this?

Comment: The insertion code looks ok to me. One thing though. If you are using `typedef` there is no need to write `struct Cons` every time. You can simply write `Cons`. As for parsing the input the since you have not given much details about it in code, I can't say much about it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code like this

```
   Cons *insert_node(Cons *head_pointer, int data){
        Cons *new = (struct Cons*) malloc(sizeof(struct Cons));
        Cons *current = head_pointer;
        new->head = data;
        new->tail = NULL;

         if (head_pointer== NULL){
             head_pointer->tail = new;
         }
      else
       {

            while (current->tail != NULL){
               current = current->tail;
       }
           current->tail = new;
    }
 //free(current);
  //current = NULL; 
    return head_poiner;
  }
```

in a main() function call like;

```
    main()
     {
      ..........
      ..........
      while(fgets()!=NULL){

       head_pointer=insert_node(head_pointer,data);
     .........
     .........

     }
```

Comment: but then how would I use what `insert_node` returns to actually insert the node? Could you update your code to show an example or an implementation

Comment: @cp101020304 Each time of calling the `insert_node() function`, you just pass the `head_pointer as call by value`, when your adding the nodes, it will not affect the original pointer in the `main() function` , that is why we return the pointer.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you give an example?

Comment: @cp101020304 - consider you have a nodes like when call the `insert_node function` `|1|->|2|->|3|->NULL` and you just send the pointer of `1 to insert_node function` this is call by value calling, so that will go as a local variable for that function, then you are adding the value `4 like |1|->|2|->|3|->|4|->NULL`, it will not affect the value of the `main() function`, to do that we are return the value.

Comment: So lets say I have an int that I want to insert into the linked list. What would  I do after the ` head_pointer=insert_node(head_pointer,data);` line in the code? Or does that automatically add the int to the linked list for me?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code I have experimented.

```
    # include <stdio.h>
     # include <stdlib.h>
    struct node
    {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
   };
   struct node *insert(struct node *p, int n)
    {
    struct node *temp;
    /*  if the existing list is empty then insert a new node as the
     *  starting node */
    if(p==NULL)
    {
            if((p=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)))==NULL)
            {
                    perror("Error");
                    exit(0);
            }
            p-> data = n;
            p-> link = p; /*  makes the pointer pointing to itself because it
                              is a circular list*/
    }
    else
    {
            temp = p;
            /*  traverses the existing list to get the pointer to the last node of
             *     it */
            while (temp-> link != p)
                    temp = temp-> link;
            if((temp-> link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)))==NULL)
            {
                    perror("Error\n");
                    exit(0);
            }
            temp = temp-> link;
            temp-> data = n;
            temp-> link = p;
    }
    return p;
   }
    void printlist ( struct node *p )
    {
    struct node *temp;
    temp = p;
    printf("The data values in the list are\n");
    if(p!= NULL)
    {
            do
            {
                    printf("%d\t",temp->data);
                    temp=temp->link;
            } while (temp!= p);
            printf("\n");
    }
             else
            printf("The list is empty\n");
      }
  void main()
    {
    int n;
    int x;
    struct node *start = NULL ;
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    while(fgets(buf,BUFSIZ,stdin)!=NULL){
            x=atoi(buf);
            start = insert ( start, x );
    }
    printlist ( start );
    }
```